# how to call struts action class from jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

Hi this is my bit of code,
my action configuration in jquery to meet calender action class failed. 
In my struts xml  in CalenderAction package if i configure extends as struts-default,json-default my welcome file is not loading.

> jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },  
        defaultDate: '2016-08-08', 
         editable: false,
        dataType: 'json', 
        events: '/democalender/CalendarJsonServlet'
    });
});
</script>
```

> struts.xml

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">

            <action name="login" class="com.giri.infonex.controller.login.LoginAction">
                <result name="success">AdminHome.jsp</result>
                <result name="ParentHomePage">ParentHomePage.jsp</result>
                <result name="AdminHome">AdminHome.jsp</result>
                <result name="error">StudentRegister.jsp</result>
            </action>
            <action name="ParentRegister"
                class="com.giri.infonex.controller.Register.ParentRegisterAction">
                <result name="success">ParentsRegister.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>

        <package name="CalenderAction" extends="json-default">
            <action name="/Student-Management-Real/CalenderAction"
                class="com.giri.infonex.controller.calender.CalenderAction">
                <result type="json" />
            </action>
        </package>
    </struts>
```

> action class

```
public class CalenderAction extends ActionSupport {
public String execute(){
        System.out.println("calender");
}
}
```

Comment: i have done changes to meet struts action class is sucessful, in struts xml CalenderAction package i am returning json data how to mention particular jsp in result

Comment: if you want jsp just mention it in struts xml

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jquery $.ajax method. You should add an attribute in your CalenderAction in order to be able to get the attribute value in .done(data) method.

For example:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: "/Student-Management-Real/CalenderAction",
      cache: false
 })
 .done(function( data ) {
     // handle your data
     // example: data.actionAttribute
 });
```